# algorithm for sorting string number in php

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, numerical

I want to write a program that  take string numeric as input(eg,one,two,three etc) and output will be sorted by ascending order or descending order of that string and show it in string as given in input.

Example:

Input:five,two,seven,ten,four

Output:two,four,five,seven,ten

Comment: If you want to write it, just start writing. What's the trouble? Conversion of spelling into number? Sorting structures? Printing saved spelling?

Comment: but the string value  (one ,two ,three etc) will come from database

Comment: Please specify programming language, DB library, DB type and version, input and output spec.

Comment: programming language : php , Sql data database

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem... You could use that Package: [Numbers_Words](http://pear.php.net/package-info.php?package=Numbers_Words)
It has til now only the function "toWords", but should easily be extended with toNumbers. Just downloaded it an looked into the code, don't look to complicated.

Comment: is it for any language or any pirticular?

Comment: in this case for PHP, but I'm sure you can use the data in any language with little changes

Comment: What i can see it converts number to words but does it converts word to numbers